# apportcheckresume recurring error and gnome shell fixations

Tags: gnome, suspend, apport

Since installing Ubuntu 12.10 Gnome remix I encounter unpredictable and unwanted behavior of my system.

Almost after each resume from suspend (or even after unlocking the screen after it goes blank) I get **apportcheckresume error** and message **Ubuntu 12.10 has encountered an internal error**. Many times the system event wont resume and I need to restart it. Other times log in screen is not visible, the screen is blank and i have to write my password `in blanco`.

Sometimes additional things also happen - textures get messed up and background and windows get distorted by horizontal lines

Sorry I can't localize the log file for the errors. My system specification:

> Ubuntu 12.10 3.5.0-19-generic Gnome 3.6 Thinkpad T400 Graphics Mobile
>   Intel® GM45 Express Chipset Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU P8600

Comment: Google apportcheckresume, and you'll get a dozen hits related to this. I'm also having the same issue with Xubuntu desktop originslly installed as unity. [see this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/1040353)

Comment: Google it was the first thing I did. I saw the bug report on lunchpad previously. Just in my case there is something else to do with it. I seams the new Gnome log in screen is causing some problems. With the newest kernel I do not get so many apportcheckresume errors but there are still some of those fixations i have mentioned above

Comment: Please post your solution if/when you find one. Not sure if our issues are related, but if I work it out, I will post it here too. :)

Comment: Does anyone know how to get a stacktrace of this? I think the obvious answer is to try to add `import pdb;pdb.set_trace` into `/usr/share/apport/apportcheckresume` and then put  the machine into suspend and possibly out?

Comment: Was facing the same problem!Removed apport! :)

Answer (score 26):

So far the only thing that has actually worked is:

1. Purge the apport program with its configuration

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge apport
   ```
2. Remove packages that are no longer needed (ex. auto-installed dependencies of apport)

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
3. Clean APT cache from old packages

   ```
   sudo apt-get clean
   ```
4. Install back apport

   ```
   sudo apt-get install apport
   ```

Hopefully that will work for you.

I think the problem for me at least is that I originally had Unity but have switched to Xubuntu. So I had several apparently orphaned packages that where still being used by `apport`, `apport-gtk`, etc. Removing these packages and purging the their config files, then reinstalling and configured just the needed Xubuntu apport packages. Example: I did not reinstall `apport-gtk`.

Comment: you should also install apport-gtk, as it gets uninstalled with the purge

Answer (score 5):

Try the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge apport
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install apport
```

The commands will

- remove the apport program
- remove packages that are no longer needed (ex. dependencies of apport)
- remove all packages files saved in the cache
- (re)install apport

More details on `apt-get` can be found in the [AptGet HowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) guide.

Comment: [Imitation is the sincerest form of flattery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Caleb_Colton#cite_note-1) Thanks!

Comment: you should also install apport-gtk, as it gets uninstalled with the purge

Comment: What is the difference between this answer than Mark's one, except it is less elaborate?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I had the same type of error. I don't know if they are really related, but after using these commands and restarting the laptop, I have discovered that the sound doesn't work at all. I have checked all the settings and players: they are all at maximum yet the system is mute!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issues.

At least in my case it was conflicting extensions. If you have any of the gnome-extensions installed try deactivating them. Once I did this I stopped having troubles.